# Problem with inserting curdate to database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I keep getting an error when trying to insert the current date to MySQL Database. I got table pictures with different columns. One of them, picture_upload, is supposed to have the date, when picture is uploaded.

I keep getting an error

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 
1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 in 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pinterest/profile.php:57 Stack trace: #0 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pinterest/profile.php(57): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main}Success
```

[See my pictures table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQih8.png)

```
{
    $sName = $_POST['name'];
    $img = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $sUserId = $_SESSION['txtUsername'];

    try{
        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO pictures VALUES (null, :sName, :sImage, 'curdate()', :sUserId, 0, 0)");
        $stmt->bindValue(':sName', $sName);
        $stmt->bindValue(':sImage', $img);
        $stmt->bindValue(':sUserId', $aRow->user_id);

        $stmt->execute();

    }catch (PDOEXception $ex){
        echo $ex;
    }
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "images/$img");
    echo 'Success';
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: try to remove quote from curdate()

Comment: Please include the definition for the `pictures` table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I updated the post, there is a link. thank you!

Comment: add the fieldnames your are trying to insert, `INSERT INTO pictures (picture_name, picture_path, upload_date, use_rid, pic_like, pic_dislike) VALUES (….`,

Comment: @Luuk thanks but unfortunately it did not help :/

Comment: why 'did not help'? what error did you get?.... never mind, see response from @Tim B.

Answer (score 2):

You should *always* explicitly list out the columns being targeted by the insert:

```
try {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO pictures (picture_name, picture_path, upload_date, use_rid, pic_like, pic_dislike) ";
    $sql .= "VALUES (:sName, :sImage, CURDATE(), :sUserId, 0, 0)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':sName', $sName);
    $stmt->bindValue(':sImage', $img);
    $stmt->bindValue(':sUserId', $aRow->user_id);

    $stmt->execute();
} catch (PDOEXception $ex) {
    echo $ex;
}
```

Notes:

- As `picture_id` is an auto increment column, if you want MySQL to automatically assign a sequence value, you should omit this column from the insert.  Then, MySQL will handle choosing the value.
- `CURDATE()` does *not* take single quotes, as it is a function call.